# 3 sql inner joined tables, now how to count total rows in them

Tags: php, mysql, mybb

here is the query, I have inner joined 3 tables, Now i am looking to count all rows in the result i.e. 78 by executing query on php my admin, I don't want result of table, i jst want 1 row in wchich only thing written is 78, same as we do in

```
SELECT count (*) FROM test_table
```

Below is the query of 3 inner joined tables

```
        SELECT 
mybb_users.uid,
mybb_users.username,
mybb_users.avatar,
mybb_posts.fid,
mybb_posts.uid,
mybb_posts.dateline,
mybb_posts.tid,
mybb_posts.subject,
mybb_forums.parentlist,
mybb_forums.fid
FROM mybb_forums
    INNER JOIN mybb_posts ON mybb_forums.fid = mybb_posts.fid
    INNER JOIN mybb_users ON mybb_posts.uid = mybb_users.uid
    WHERE mybb_forums.parentlist LIKE '%58%'
    GROUP BY mybb_posts.tid
    ORDER BY mybb_posts.dateline DESC
```

now how to count total number of rows in it ?

**EDITED**

```
 SELECT count( mybb_users.uid ) AS totalOfRows
FROM (

SELECT mybb_users.uid, mybb_users.username, mybb_users.avatar, mybb_posts.fid, mybb_posts.uid AS uidPost, mybb_posts.dateline, mybb_posts.tid, mybb_posts.subject, mybb_forums.parentlist, mybb_forums.fid AS fidForum
FROM mybb_forums
INNER JOIN mybb_posts ON mybb_forums.fid = mybb_posts.fid
INNER JOIN mybb_users ON mybb_posts.uid = mybb_users.uid
WHERE mybb_forums.parentlist LIKE '%58%'
GROUP BY mybb_posts.tid
)T
```

Error ::#1054 - Unknown column 'mybb_users.uid' in 'field list'

Comment: sekect count(myb_users.uid) from mybb_forums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, if you don't want the result, why are you showing those fields ? A select return one table, so apply count to it:

```
SELECT 
count(*)
FROM mybb_forums
    INNER JOIN mybb_posts ON mybb_forums.fid = mybb_posts.fid
    INNER JOIN mybb_users ON mybb_posts.uid = mybb_users.uid
    WHERE mybb_forums.parentlist LIKE '%58%'
    GROUP BY mybb_posts.tid
```

Also, you're groupying by posts, so, don't need to order

Edit:
I think the query I've posted should work, anyway, if it's not, this definitely should work:

```
SELECT sum(Total) AS totalOfRows 
FROM ( 

SELECT 1 as Total 
FROM mybb_forums 
INNER JOIN mybb_posts ON mybb_forums.fid = mybb_posts.fid 
INNER JOIN mybb_users ON mybb_posts.uid = mybb_users.uid 
WHERE mybb_forums.parentlist LIKE '%58%' 
GROUP BY mybb_posts.tid 
)T
```

Comment: this is the problem, this query is giving me result like
+-----------+
| count(*)  |
|-----------|
| 1         |
| 2         |
| 3         |
| 7         |
| 4         |
| 1         |
+-----------+

Comment: like.. what ? well, if this don't work, remove the order to your original query, use it as a subquery and just do select count(*) from (yourquery) t

Comment: I know this query would work, but it's not giving a single record, it's giving all 75 records how to echo the number 75 :(

Comment: :( #1060 - Duplicate column name 'uid'

Comment: and you can't fix that ? it's not magical copypaste. You should show some effort - is the column uid repeated between table users and posts. See the edited

Comment: I showed efforts that i know, :p this query is making me blind, seriously i don't have much command on mysql, see my edited post

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15803/discussion-between-programer-and-elvieejo)